# OAuth Google callback throws error "connection attempt to localhost was rejected"

Tags: node.js, oauth, google-oauth, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

I am new to `node.js` and I was trying to implement `OAuth 2.0` with `Google` using `passport.js`.

I have my `clientID` , `clientSecret` and `Authorized Redirect URLs` from Google Developer Console. The callback URL is something like `http://localhost:portNumber/foo/bar/callback` and the application works perfectly when I run it from my machine.

The problem occurs when I try to access it over the Internet using a Public IP Address. I am able to access my website but as soon as I allow my application to access my `Google+` profile using `OAuth` it gives an error `connection attempt to localhost was rejected`. It gives an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error for my callback URL.

I am stuck as I do not have a domain right now to use instead of `localhost`.

Kindly excuse me if my question is vague and any help would be appreciated.

P.S : I have forwarded my port.

Comment: Did you tried to add your IP address as additional redirect URL in the Google's developer console? Like: `http://[IP]:[PORT]/foo/bar/callback`

Comment: Yes, I tried doing that but as it turns out you cannot put a public ip address in  Authorized Redirect URIs

Comment: Try this: http://localtunnel.me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in my comment from above you can use [localtunnel.me](http://localtunnel.me):

1. Install the `localtunnel` module on your workstation: `npm install -g localtunnel`
2. Run you web server as usual: `node app.js`
3. Run tunnel for your web server: `lt --port 3000` (`3000` is the port your server listens to)
4. After you run the tunnel from above you will receive a URL in return: `https://glsjjuobon.localtunnel.me` (`glsjjuobon` is a randomly generated string)
5. Use the above URL to add additional *Authorized Redirect URI* in the Google's developer console for your project: `https://glsjjuobon.localtunnel.me/connect/google/callback`

That's it! As long as your local server and the tunnel are both running you can use the generated URL from `localtunnel` to access your web site.

Comment: You are awesome. Its perfectly working now. Thanks aot